# Quand le r final porte-t-il un accent tonique ?

Tags: phonétique, paroles-de-chanson, dialectes

Je viens d’observer en écoutant la bande originale du film *Un homme et une femme* que dans la chanson *Plus fort que nous*, Nicole Croisille a mis l’accent sur deux r finaux :

> l’amou-re est bien plus for-re que nous.

Est-ce peut-être une simple particularité de son idiolecte ? Ou même une charactéristique dialectale de sa région natale, savoir les Hauts-de-Seine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'accent tonique est en général peu marqué en « français du nord de la Loire » mais il peut l'être plus dans un poème ou une chanson.

Comme l'écrasante majorité des chanteurs et comédiens français, Nicole Croisille parle ce français qualifié de « sans accent », que l'on entend aussi dans les chaînes de radio ou de télévision parisiennes, et de plus en plus ailleurs. Contrairement à certains artistes « montés à Paris », Nicole Croisille n'a pas eu besoin de prendre de cours pour gommer un quelconque accent provincial puisqu'elle avait déjà naturellement l'accent attendu.

Dans le sud de la France, *amour* ou *fort* peuvent êtres prononcés un peu comme *amoure* ou *for-re* mais ce ne sont pas ces prononciations que l'on peut entendre dans les extraits des œuvres citées bien que leur compositeur Francis Lai, niçois, avait lui un accent méridional.

La région natale de Nicole Croisille est l'Île-de-France. Il n'y a pas de spécificité dialectale associée au département des Hauts-de-Seine et encore moins à Neuilly, ville limitrophe et même quasiment indifférenciée des « beaux quartiers » de Paris.